# Is using the Open Graph Protocol helpful, harmless, or harmful to SEO?

Tags: seo, html5, google-ranking, open-graph-protocol, rdfa

I am doing an SEO project and I noticed that all of the meta tags have an "og" in the `property` attribute of the tag, such as:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

I'm wondering if using the Open Graph Protocol is helpful or possible harmful to SEO and what is the best practice?

I think it's supposed to make it easier for Facebook and other social networks to share the metadata on your site, but what I really care about is the Google organic search ranking.

So should I repeat/double the `description` `meta` tag with one that does not have the `og` `property`, or remove the `og` `property`, or just leave it in because the `og` `property` is harmless to SEO?

Comment: Open Graph has absolutely no direct effect on search performance, but is said to effect social media positively. Check out https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/

Comment: These are meta tags and more of guidelines for machines than content. It does not have any positive or negative effect on SEO.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it wouldn't have any effect on the search rankings, the main purpose of the open graph tags is to make it prettier if the page is shared on social media.

Hope this helps.

If you are using PHP, you could always do the following so you end up with the same description for the meta description tag and the og:description tag:

```
<?php     
$description = "Search Engine Optimisation"; 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Meta Tags for Page Related Properties -->
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not at all. Google does not using open graph meta tags, neither in Search Snippet/Result nor in Search Ranking.**

Ref - [Meta Tags That Google Understand](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)

OGP is useful for Social Media, because you can use different title in og:title tag, and different images to get more CTR.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you try to deceive, there is no reason to assume that it could hurt your ranking. But providing structured data typically has no direct influence on the ranking anyway, so it wouldn’t help either.

If you want to provide a `meta`-`description` in addition to `og:description`, you don’t have to duplicate the description, because [RDFa allows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429551/1591669) to use `property` and `name` on the same `meta` element:

```html
<meta name="description" property="og:description" content="great description" />
```

The same is true for `link` elements¹, e.g. if you want to provide `rel`-`canonical` in addition to `og:url`:

```html
<link rel="canonical" property="og:url" href="http://example.com/foo-1" />
```

---

¹ `link` must be used instead of `meta` if the value is a URI (this is [required by HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669), but the OGP/Facebook documentation [doesn’t seem to](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/82527/17633) care)